# AccessibleObjectFromPoint and per-monitor DPI

Tags: windows, winapi, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm using accessibility with the `AccessibleObjectFromPoint` function, and I'd like it to work correctly on a per-monitor DPI environment. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I tried many things, and the situation for now is:

- My app is marked as per-monitor-DPI-aware in the manifest. (`True/PM`)
- I use `GetCursorPos` and then `AccessibleObjectFromPoint`.

How can the problem be reproduced:

- Have two monitors, one with 100% DPI, the other with 125%.
- Run Chrome on the 125% monitor.
- Use `AccessibleObjectFromPoint` on one of the tab names, it won't work.

It works with some apps (DPI-aware, it seems, like explorer), but doesn't work with others. I tried several relevant functions, such as `GetPhysicalCursorPos` and `PhysicalToLogicalPointForPerMonitorDPI`, but nothing works.

It's worth noting that Microsoft's `inspect.exe` works as expected.

Comment: Is the OS 8.1, 10.0.10240, 10.0.10586, or 10.0.14393. The api keeps changing. At win 7 it all worked on physical co-ordinates. I had some code that worked on 10586 that breaks on 14393. If the window is maximised you can get monitor info, subtract the monitor origin, and multiply by the window dpi divided by the monitor dpi. Then re add the monitor origin. That works on 14393 if the window is maximised. I have the same problem and am still investigating.

Comment: The reason I mention the three versions of Windows 10 is e.g. the Win32 API call GetDpiForWindow() is only available from 14393 onwards.  My client's clients have LTS versions of 10.0.10240 and 10.0.10586, so these are still in the wild for at least many months yet.  So I had to write a .NET wrapper in C++/CLI the works with everything from Vista to 10.0.14393.  Load the User32.dll and Shcore.dll dynamically at runtime and pull in the function pointers (or NULL) to figure out what OS variant you are executing on, and react accordingly.

Comment: P.S.  Since 14393 and thread DPI awareness, using the manifest is now out of fashion.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302122(v=vs.85).aspx

Call SetProcessDpiAwareness if on 8.1+ or SetProcessDPIAware() if on Win 7 or Vista.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been struggling with this exact same problem for several weeks and can now tell you my findings.  Unfortunately I can’t give you more than a hint of code, because the project I am working on, is proprietary.

The issue started at Windows 8.1.  The problem did not exist on Windows 7 or Vista, because AccessibleObjectFromPoint always used raw physical coordinates, as documented here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317984(v=vs.85).aspx .
“Microsoft Active Accessibility does not use logical coordinates. The following methods and functions either return physical coordinates or take them as parameters.”  This has not been true since Windows 8.1.

AccessibleObjectFromPoint now uses a flawed calculation that cannot always find the correct window for reasons similar to my question here: [High DPI scaling, mouse hooks and WindowFromPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39677569/high-dpi-scaling-mouse-hooks-and-windowfrompoint/39678242#39678242) .
My findings lead me to one conclusion: The API is broken.  This does not mean it is not possible though.

Possible solutions I have partially tested that seem to work follow.
Prerequisites are that you

1/.  Make your process per monitor DPI aware, NOT USING THE MANIFEST  (more on that later).

2/. Determine the hWnd of the window you want to query (WindowFromPoint() variants)

3/. Determine the monitor DPI of the queried hWnd

4/. Determine the DPI of your process

5/. Determine the DPI of the queried hWnd

6/. Determine the monitor origin and offset for the queried hWnd (MonitorFromWindow() and GetMonitorInfo() )

Next, depends on your platform

**Windows 10.0.14393+**

Write a function that finds the IAccessible (AccessibleObjectFromWindow() ) from the top level window, and then recursively call IAccessible::accHitTest until you reach the bottom-most IAccessible and perhaps ChildID data.  Return that as if you would call AccessibleObjectFromPoint.

To call it successfully, you will need to scale the (x,y) co-ordinates into the scale system of the queried hWnd, using the DPIs and co-ordinates fetched in the list above.  Watch out for systems where monitors are not the same size or if monitors are partially offset, or above and below.

And now for the important part for 10.0.14393 – Set your thread to the same DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT of the hWnd you are querying.  Now call your new function.  Now revert your thread to monitor DPI aware, and voila, it works, even if the window is not maximised.  This is why you must not use the manifest.

If you are on Windows **8.1 to 10.0.10586** you have a tougher task.
Instead of calling accHitTest, as above, you have to recursively call AccessibleChildren and iterate the call IAccessible::accLocation to determine if your test point is within each child.  This is tricky and starts to get really messy when you get to e.g. combo boxes in products like Office, which is only system DPI aware.

That’s all I can give you for now.

To do it successfully on multi-platform (mine has to work from Vista to Windows-Current) the only really safe bet is to write a wrapper DLL in C++ that can determine at runtime which OS it is on and change code path accordingly.  The reason you want to do it in C++ is to avoid passing IAccessible objects across the .Net/unmanaged marshalling boundary.  You can call IUnknown::Release on objects you don’t need to return n the unmanaged side.  You can do it all in .Net, but it will be slow.

P.S. also watch out for Chrome returning infinite trees where parents are children of their parents, some snity checks are required.  Also, Chrome does not return accRole correctly, and will give you HTML tags instead of VT_I4.

Good luck

Comment: P.S. Benchmarks that I have done in .Net vs C++ are in the region of 20-50 times faster in C++.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly workable solution is as follows, in your `IAccessible` recursive function:

- Use `getwindowrect` to capture the physical right on main window
- Use `accChild.accLocation` in loop to capture left and Width on each Object

Add this simple test

```
If l > rct2r.Right And l > arrIACC.x2 Then
    arrIACC.x2 = l + w
End If
if dpi = 100 then no Object is furter out than physical right
if dpi > 100 then closebutton is...x pix offset
```

Use the difference to rescale all values you are in use of Width

```
arrIACC.w1 = CInt(((-rct2r.Left + arrIACC.w1) / arrIACC.x2) * rct2r.Right)
```

This solution is from an Excel plugin I have developed, I was testing the Width of the quick access toolbar qat and my result was +- 5 pixels regardless of any DPI.